# Как сделать выполнение какой-либо команды в питоне в опр. период времени?

Tags: python

Каждый раз перезапускать код не особо хочется, чтобы получать обновлённые данные - глупо и хотелось бы автоматизировать процесс. Можно ли сделать в питоне таймер, который бы активировал по своему окончанию код, а потом вновь отсчитывал время?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете сделать цикл:

```
import time

while True:
    time.sleep(10) # Ваш таймер, время в секундах
    # Ваш код
```

Comment: А с отсыланием на дату/время можно ли это провернуть? Чтобы не стопорить весь процесс в одном коде в целом?

Comment: @АлексейБыстрик Конечно можно, вычисляете разницу в секундах между требуемым датой/временем следующего запуска и текущим временем. И делаете sleep на полученное значение. На счет "не стопорить весь процесс" не понятно, что вы имеете ввиду

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime

while True:
    if datetime.now().date() == 'день.мес.год ' and datetime.now().time() == 'чч:мм:сс':
    # проверка даты и времени
    # ваш код
    else:
        pass
```

Comment: Мне  бы не опр. время выбрать, а период. Например, чтобы каждый новый месяц (то есть первого числа во всех месяцах) выполнялась команда